# Unable to run a React application in a docker form

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I have a small React application memegenerator application which runs marvelously in local setting without any docker properly.
gitlink:
https://github.com/ajahi/memegenerator.git
The application structure is as such.

```
-dist
 -assets
 -index.html
 -vite.svg

-Dockerfile
-index.html
-node_modules
-package,json
-public
 -vite.svg
-src
 -App.jsx
 -assets
 -components
 -index.css
 -main.jsx
-vite.config.js
```

the package.json is as such:

```
{
  "name": "meme-generator",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port=3000",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "use-react-screenshot": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  }
}
```

the Dockerfile is as such:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as builder

WORKDIR memegen

COPY ./ ./
 
#run  npm install
RUN npm install --force

EXPOSE 3000

#cmd
CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

in local instance after i install node modules with, "npm install" and then "npm run dev". the application runs in the localhost:3000. i tried to recreate the same steps i had done to run in my local setup in the docker container. to do that i followed these steps, in root dir:

> 1.docker build -t imagegene . //image is created with given Dockerfile.

> 2.docker run -p 3000:3000 imagegene

```
Response i get is:


meme-generator@0.0.0 dev
vite --port=3000


VITE v4.3.9  ready in 546 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
```

but when i goto localhost:3000 i get nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite, per default, binds to localhost, meaning that it'll only accept connections from the local machine. In a Docker context, the local machine is the container itself. So Vite doesn't accept connections from outside the container.

To fix it, you need to add `--host` to your `vite` command that is defined in the `dev` script in  your `package.json` file.

Right now it looks like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port=3000",
    "build": "vite build",
```

Change it to

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port=3000 --host",
    "build": "vite build",
```

and it should start accepting connections from outside the container.

As a note, Vite is actually trying to tell you that you might need to do this. If you look in the messages from your app startup, it says `Network: use --host to expose`. That could be formulated better, I think, since everyone might not know what 'expose' means in this context.

Comment: The best explanation. simple and concise . yes you are right about the host message and i wondered what that meant. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you. can you suggest me some resources on how to get better in dockerizing and devops in general.

Answer (score -2):

Your docker container is not accessible on "localhost". You have to find out the IP of your container and replace localhost with its IP.
You can use this command to get the IP:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

Comment: That IP address doesn't usually work.  For example, it will be unreachable if you're using Docker Desktop (on any OS).